# How to change language output with wikipedia package in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, pyttsx3

If i ask about iphone, the output is: "The iPhone is a line of smartphones designed and marketed by Apple Inc. that use Apple's iOS mobile operating system." But i want to change it into german.

```
elif 'wikipedia' in query:
            speak('Suche auf wikipedia...')
            query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
            result = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences = 2)
            print(result)
            speak(result)
```

Comment: What is `wikipedia`?

Comment: sorry, i used: import wikipedia
from wikipedia.wikipedia import search

Comment: Your question needs more clarification! Please, take a look at "How to Ask A Good Question" (stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It can help you to enhance your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After importing `wikipedia` you can set the language as follows:

```
wikipedia.set_lang('de')
```

Example:

```
import wikipedia

wikipedia.set_lang('de')

result = wikipedia.summary('Stack Overflow', sentences = 1)

print(result)
```

And the output will be:

> Pufferüberläufe (englisch buffer overflow) oder – im Besonderen – auch
> Stapelüberläufe (englisch ‚stack overflows‘) genannt, gehören zu den
> häufigsten Sicherheitslücken in aktueller Software, die sich  u.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem or you believe it is the best solution. Please, up-vote and mark this answer as accepted! Thank you! If it doesn't solve your problem, let me know!